# How to avoid execute some piece of code in oncreateview while clicking back button in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout

i am developing android application and i am trying to implement drawer layout(slider menu) in my project. Actually let me explain my project, i have one recyclerview with some gridview items so that we can able to see our home screen. i want to display drawer layout on top this grid items which means recyclerview. i would like to display my profile photo in my drawer layout(slider menu) whenever application open after that we can swipe back and as usual we can able to see our grid items.

I almost did but i have one problem. i am able to display my drawer layout(slider menu) fine whenever application open after swipe back if i click any one gridview item  and i enter into that page  and if i click back, that time also my drawer layout(slider menu) is showing but it should not show while clicking back from any grid items.
     i have given recyclerview and drawer layout(slider menu) in same xml file that is the reason whenever user click back button, recyclerview is displaying with drawer layout(slider menu)

Actually if i use activity i will not face any problem because In Activity, if i click back button it will not call oncreate method it will call onrestart method that is the reason oncreate will not execute even if i click button also.
 But in fragment my oncreateview is executing even if i click back button this is my problem because some set of code should not execute in my oncreateview if i click button. could you please help me to solve my problem.

This is my Oncreateview code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test2, container, false);

           mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        navDrawerItems.add("first");
        navDrawerItems.add("second");
        navDrawerItems.add("third");

        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getActivity(),navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
  }
```

This is my test2 layout xml code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Grid View Items -->  
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:id="@+id/fade"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Atleast i am expecting this line should not execute while clicking back button
`mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);`